# Grails Shell Initiating Bootstrap

Tags: grails

Having problem initiating the shell on grails 2.5.0 (Groovy Shell (2.2.0-rc-2, JVM: 1.8.0_25)

```
new BootStrap().init()
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: BootStrap.init() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), wait(long, int), find(), print(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter)
```

I noticed there is another unanswered maillist [topic](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-3-4-Shell-Problems-td4653040.html) with the same issue. Any reference on how to initiatel BootStrap in a shell? Would be very handy to preload a set of values

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem and could not find the solution to initialize BootStrap. There are certain other issues with shell too. So I have a workaround for me. I always use grails console instead of shell. It launches a Swing UI console (just like groovy console) and I paste Bootstrap code in it (without servlet context i.e the code inside init closure only) along with required imports. I would recommend this workaround.